# error : velocity(a vector) cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: processing

When I compile my code I get an error saying `velocity`(a vector) cannot be resolved or is not a `field`. Does anyone have some suggestions on what may be causing this error?

```java
PVector gravity;
PVector wind;
PVector friction;
Ball b;

void setup(){
    fullScreen();
    b=new Ball();
}

void draw() {
    background(240, 123, 50);
    b.update();
    //applying gravity to ball
    gravity=new PVector(0, .981);
    gravity.mult(mass);
    b.applyForce(gravity);
    //apply wind
    wind=new PVector (5, 0);
    b.applyForce(wind);
    //apply friction
```

> The below line is where the error occurs.

```java
    friction=b.velocity.get();
    friction.normalize();
    float c=-0.01;
    friction.mult(c);
    b.applyForce(friction);
    b.bounce();
    b.display();
}
```

### Here is the Ball class.

```java
PVector location;
PVector velocity;
PVector acceleration;
float mass, diam;

class Ball {
    Ball() {
        location=new PVector(width/2, height/2);
        velocity=new PVector(0, 0);
        acceleration=new PVector(0, 0);
        mass=5;
        diam=mass*20;
    }

    void update() {
        velocity.add(acceleration);
        location.add(velocity);
        acceleration.mult(0);
    }

    void applyForce(PVector force){
        PVector f=PVector.div(force,mass); 
        acceleration.add(f);
    }

    void bounce() { 
        if (location.y>=height-diam/2) {
            //hitting floor
            velocity.y*=-0.9;
            location.y=height-diam/2;
        } else if (location.y<=0) {
            //striking top
            location.y=0+diam/2;
            velocity.y*=-0.9;
        }
        if (location.x<=0+diam/2) {
            //hitting left
            location.x=0+diam/2;
            velocity.x*=-.9;
        } else if (location.x>=width-diam/2) {
            //hitting right
            location.x=width-diam/2;
            velocity.x*=-.9;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        ellipse(location.x, location.y, diam, diam);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: java has no global variables. The declaration of the fields you have preceding `class Ball {...` can't exist outside of a class.

Comment: @RobertoAttias You could have a static variable inside the class. That could be considered a global variable.

Comment: @RobertoAttias This is not really a global variable, but it does the same thing.

Comment: The point is that the code written as it is is not valid Java syntax. It would be in C++, where those would be global variables, but won't compile in Java.

Comment: @RobertoAttias Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). Specifically, you can have variables at the "sketch level" outside of a class.

Comment: @mikekane Are you using the Processing editor for this? Is the `Ball` class in a separate tab? Please explain your exact setup with as much detail as possible. Adding a screenshot might help.

Comment: @Keving Workman, the question was tagged with java too. The java tag should be removed as misleading.

Comment: I've proposed removal of java tag. BTW, the choice of "processing" as tag for a language is very unfortunate, as it's extremely generic and can easily result in this type of confusion.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions on misleading tags. I will bear that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `velocity` is not a `field` of `Ball`, it needs to be inside the `Ball` class for it to work.

Try doing this:

```java
class Ball {
    PVector location;
    PVector velocity;
    PVector acceleration;
    float mass, diam;
    Ball() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of :

```java
PVector location;
PVector velocity;
PVector acceleration;
float mass, diam;
class Ball {
    Ball() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The only difference is that I included the 5 fields in the class.

Comment: Thank you this has fixed the problem